# Include active developing subproject in your current XCode4 project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Assume you have two XCode4 projects

1. App
2. Library

Since the Library is active developing, so new headers might be added from time to time, code might be changed from time to time.

Even I can drag the Library XCode project into the App XCode project, I still need to copy the headers manually.

Are there any easy way, rather than copy the Library into the App library folder, I can develope the codes on two projects at the same time, e.g. debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few recommendations after beating my head against a wall:

Try creating an Xcode 4 workspace containing the 2 projects. It seems to work better than having one be a sub-project of the other.

Instead of copying the headers, add their path to the "header search paths", then select "always search user paths" (both in build settings).

To get started: [Xcode 4 workspace docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/ExistingProject/ExistingProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH2-SW7)

Comment: One of the problem in this approach is when I changed the Library code, the static library is still the same if I do not build the Library. Are there any easy way to auto build the Library if any code changed?

Comment: The workspace is supposed to figure out the dependencies on its own, which it does for me. I added the library from the first project to the "Link Library With Libraries" phase of the second project and it all works.